# React display n number of elements on page and keep the rest idle

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating a react app and I want to only show 21 number of elements at a time while keeping the rest in idle. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, show another 21 elements, and repeat this process until all the elements are visible.

I have my function `_injectAdsInList`  that gets the products and inserts an add every 20 products this works but when I want to only show 21 elements at a time (20 products and 1 add) while keeping the rest idle to load another 21 elements when they scroll down I get an error on the screen and in my console doing a console log my array `displayedList` is coming back as `undefined`.

This is my component.

```
    import React from "react";
import { Loading } from "./LoadingComponent";

const axios = require('axios');

class Products extends React.Component {


  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
      displayedList : [],
      indexDisplayed : 0,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null
    }
    }



  _injectAdsInList = list => {
    // an array of your ads

    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    const AdsList = ['111','2222'];

    let displayedList = this.state.displayedList;
    let indexDisplayed = this.state.displayedList;

    if (Array.isArray(list)) {
      const insertAdAt = 21;

      const productsAndAdsList = list.map((item, index) => {
        // not sure about this calculation
        // but this should be done here

        if (index % insertAdAt === 0 && index !== 0) {
          // its the 20th item insert an ad
          return AdsList[0];
        }

        // otherwise insert the item


        return item;



        });


        for(let i = indexDisplayed +1; i <= indexDisplayed + 21; i++ ){
         displayedList.push(productsAndAdsList[i]);
        }






      this.setState({productsAndAdsList});



    }
  };





  _getProducts = () => {

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products').then(list => this._injectAdsInList(list.data))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  };

  _addToDisplay = ()=> {

    let displayedList = this.state.displayedList;
    let indexDisplayed = this.state.displayedList;
    let productsAndAdsList = this.state.displayedList;
        for(let i = indexDisplayed +1 ; i <= indexDisplayed + 21; i++ ){
            displayedList.push(productsAndAdsList[i]);
        }

        this.setState({
            indexDisplayed : this.state.indexDisplayed+21, displayedList : displayedList }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.displayedList)
        });
    }


  _sortPrice = () => {
    const { displayedList } = this.state;

    const sortedProducts = displayedList.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    this.setState({ displayedList: sortedProducts });
  };

  _sortSize = () => {
    const { displayedList } = this.state;

    const sortedProducts = displayedList.sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size);
    this.setState({ displayedList: sortedProducts });
  };

  _sortId = () => {
    const { displayedList } = this.state;  
    const sortedProducts =  displayedList.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.id < b.id)
    return -1;
  if (a.id > b.id)
    return 1;
  return 0;
});
    this.setState({ displayedList: sortedProducts });
  }

   _timeAgo = (prevDate) => {
        const diff = Number(new Date()) - prevDate;
        const minute = 60 * 1000;
        const hour = minute * 60;
        const day = hour * 24;
        const month = day * 30;
        const year = day * 365;
        switch (true) {
            case diff < minute:
                const seconds = Math.round(diff / 1000);
                 return `${seconds} ${seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second'} ago`
            case diff < hour:
                return Math.round(diff / minute) + ' minutes ago';
            case diff < day:
                return Math.round(diff / hour) + ' hours ago';
            case diff < month:
                return Math.round(diff / day) + ' days ago';
            case diff < year:
                return Math.round(diff / month) + ' months ago';
            case diff > year:
                return Math.round(diff / year) + ' years ago';
            default:
                return "";
        }
    };

  componentDidMount() {

    this._getProducts();
  }

  render() {

    const { displayedList, isLoading, hasError } = this.state;

console.log(this.state.displayedList);

    // show spinner
    if (!hasError && isLoading) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    // show error
    if (hasError && !isLoading) {
      return <p>error.message</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <button onClick={this._sortPrice}>sort by price lower to higher</button>
                <button onClick={this._sortSize}>sort by size small to big</button>
                <button onClick={this._sortId}>sort by Id</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
        { displayedList.map(item => { return (
                        <div className="row">
              <div className="col-4">
                <p> Price: ${(item.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</p>
              </div>

              <div className="col-4">
                <p style={{ fontSize: `${item.size}px` }}> {item.face}</p>
              </div>
            <div className="col-3">
                  <p>Published: {this._timeAgo(new Date(item.date).getTime())}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            ) } )

                }



       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <p>END OF CATALOG</p>  
            </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

This is my error.

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
```

This is my original data from database

```
 {
    "id": "29470-8qkpkhuqdct",
    "size": 15,
    "price": 999,
    "face": "( .-. )",
    "date": "Tue Nov 05 2019 20:29:01 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "38405-fq66zcem9a5",
    "size": 27,
    "price": 787,
    "face": "( .o.)",
    "date": "Thu Nov 07 2019 13:32:17 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "21765-r5f5rctbs6i",
    "size": 24,
    "price": 619,
    "face": "( `·´ )",
    "date": "Mon Nov 11 2019 20:57:19 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "82780-5sypj693ojx",
    "size": 26,
    "price": 994,
    "face": "( ° ͜ ʖ °)",
    "date": "Fri Nov 15 2019 12:20:46 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
```

This is what I get in my console log repeated 4 times

[]
0: {id: "71853-4k9d13grmxj", size: 19, price: 4, face: "( .o.)", date: "Thu Nov 21 2019 11:06:00 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"}
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)

Comment: components/ProductsComponent.js:183 witch refers to    <p> Price: ${(item.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</p>

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.state.displayedList)` after setting state at the end of ` _injectAdsInList`. So write `this.setState({productsAndAdsList,indexDisplayed  : this.state.indexDisplayed+21, displayedList : displayedList }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.displayedList)});`

Comment: ok I copied and pasted what you told me to write and I get this array in my console repeated 4 times: 
[]
0: undefined
1: {id: "71853-4k9d13grmxj", size: 19, price: 4, face: "( .o.)", date: "Thu Nov 21 2019 11:06:00 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Can you add it to the question? That array looks confusing. It should look more like `[{id: "71853-4k9d13grmxj", size: 19, price: 4, face: "( .o.)", date: "Thu Nov 21 2019 11:06:00 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"}, {...}, ...]`

Comment: Better yet maybe just add an example response from the initial request in `componentDidMount` so we can see what the data is supposed to look like.

Comment: ok added what I get in the console and part of the original array

Comment: Awesome. Now what is being passed as the `list` in the function? And what purpose does `AdsList = ['111','2222']` serve?

Comment: I intend to replace the array with a script I was giving to generate random adds. The list passed is the products array I get with  axios

Comment: I changed my code so that the loop thru the array is in another function and not in the same one that adds the list. Now my array is empty again? I am really lost.

Comment: I've opened a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ri5ke?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that might help us collaborate. Feel free to fork it. I've made some changes to you code in `injectedAdsInList`